# Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am trying to make a login page from cross domain but I couldn't solve the problem, the error is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/testing/resp.php. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

My Javascript code is:

```js
$('#login').click(function(){
  var username = $('#uname').val();
  var password = $('#pass').val();
  var result = $('.result');
  result.text('loading....');

  if (username != '' && password !=''){
   var urltopass = 'action=login&username='+username+'&password='+password;
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: urltopass,
    headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"},
    url: 'http://localhost/testing/resp.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(responseText){
     console.log(responseText);
     if(responseText== "0"){
      result.text('incorrect login information');
     } else if (responseText == "1"){
      window.location="http://localhost/testing/home.php";
     } else{
      alert('error in sql query \n' + responseText);
     }
    }
   });
  } else return false;
 });
```

The PHP code for http://localhost/testing/resp.php :

```js
<?php
 include "db.php"; //Connecting to database

 if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
  echo "This is not cross-domain request";
    exit;
}
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
 header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"'); // Makes IE to support cookies
 header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

 if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login'){
  $uname = $_POST['username'];
  $pass = $_POST['password'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM loginajax WHERE username='$uname' AND password='$pass'";
 
  $rs=$conn->query($sql);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($rs) <= 0){
   echo "0";
  } else {
   echo "1";
  }
  
 } else echo "this is not Login";

?>
```

Comment: can you use the browser dev tools to find out what headers are actually being returned? On a more general note: not a good idea to allow login from all domains, this leaves you vulnerable to things like CSRF (standard validation token defense *requires* that browser disallows cross origin requests).

Comment: Your server gives the preflight requests. The PHP is rendered by the server. You must return the header from the server engine itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

remove this:

```
headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"},
```

from your jQuery.ajax call.

The server responds with a `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header, the client doesn't send it to the server.

The client sends a `Access-Control-Request-Headers` to request allowing certain headers, the server responds back with with a `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` that lists the actual headers its going to allow. The client does not get to demand what headers are allowed.

Comment: The request header disapeared, but I don't receive any answer from the server

Comment: @Anahoua16, add an error callback to your ajax options, ie `error:function(){}` and see if its getting triggered if so log the status/error that is passed

Comment: Status: 200
textStatus: parsererror
errorThrown: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s

Comment: Now it is working, I was puting echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; to debug, when I removed it everything works fine, thankyou