# phpswagger rest API cors error

Tags: zend-framework, swagger

How to fix cors error while accessing **Swagger-API** from another machine with different host i.e **Swagger-API** is hosted in one machine and *swagger-ui* is hosted in another machine. It works fine with curl command but accessing from *swagger-ui* it returns:

```
 "{error:no response from server"}.
```

This Rest API is implemented in **PHP Zend Framework**.

Comment: Check this:https://www.dinochiesa.net/?p=754

Comment: thank you for responding but where should i place this code in zend. After adding this code in api i got following error (XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://idm_api.com/index. Request header field user is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35232130/5934435

Comment: i got $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD"] is post and this header is {"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"} not set in ajax